# Postgres error running seeds.exs (in production only) when a field is of Ecto type {:array, :string}

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've defined in my model one filed of Ecto type {:array, :string}. It is working OK in development but I'm getting this error when trying to run seeds.exs in production only:

```
Ecto.ChangeError value ["images/specific/eventos/sixtyfive/1.jpg", "images/specific/eventos/sixtyfive/2.jpg", "images/specific/eventos/sixtyfive/3.jpg", "images/specific/eventos/sixtyfive/4.jpg", "images/specific/eventos/sixtyfive/5.jpg"] for `FabASA.Evento.imgPath` in `insert` does not match type :string
```

Do I need to change the type in my migrations?

Comment: Is the type in your migration not `{:array, :string}`?

Comment: This looks like your production database type the field is just string... Did your check this manually with `psql` or something like this?

Comment: @Dogbert. Yes. Both in my Model and Migration. I had an issue once and I had to change the migration type for a native PostgreSQL type (not an Ecto type). So, I'm trying to see if anyone has experience with this particular Ecto type - PostgreSQL type.

Comment: @fahrradflucht. What's the psql command to see that when connected to the db?

Comment: `\d tablename` should read `character varying(255)[]` on the field.
Most likely it's `\d evento`.

Comment: @fahrradflucht Exactly:  `character varying(255)`. So I need to know the correct type to place in my migration file I think...Enum? And also why this happens only in production mode.

Comment: But `{:array, :string}` is definitely correct if that's what is in your migration. Are you sure that all the migrations ran against you production database?